# How associated(typealias) type and Self in protocols work?

Tags: swift, protocols, type-alias

Sorry, I am a newbie in programming, I try to express what i want to ask. Please forgive me.
I have seen something like this in protocol.

```
protocol Pro1 {
    typealias Element
    // ...
}
protocol Pro2: Pro1 {
    typealias Element = Self
    // ...
}
```

`Element` in protocols, does this `Element` relate to each other?

And I don't understand what the following expression means:

```
typealias Element = Self
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pro1

Writing this

```
protocol Pro1 {
    typealias Element
}
```

you are just telling that there will be a type named `Element`.

### Pro2

Adding this

```
protocol Pro2: Pro1 {
    typealias Element = Self
}
```

you are telling to the compiler that `Element` will be the same type of the type that is implementing `Pro2`.

**So yes, there is a relation** between the `Element` in `Pro1` and `Pro2`.

### Adding methods to Pro1

Let's declare 2 methods that will use `Element` in `Pro1`

```
protocol Pro1 {
    typealias Element
    func a() -> Element
    func b(elm: Element)
}
```

### Conforming to Pro1

Now a class conform to `Pro1` will be like this.

```
class Foo: Pro1 {
    func a() -> String {
        return ""
    }
    func b(elm: String) {
    }
}
```

As you can see we are forced by the compiler to set the return type of `a` and the param of `b` to be of the **same type**.

### Conforming to Pro2

Now let's try to conform another class to Pro2. Again `Pro1` will force us to declare methods `a` and `b` where the return type of a is equals to the param of `b`.
Furthermore `Pro2` will force us to set this type equals to the type of the current type `Boo`.

So the previous class will to conform to `Pro2` because `String` is different from `Foo`

```
class Foo: Pro2 {
    func a() -> String { // <- compiler error
        return ""
    }
    func b(elm: String) { // <- compiler error

    }
}
```

But if we declare a new class and replace `Element` with `Boo` it will work because the constraints of both protocols are satisfied.

```
class Boo: Pro2 {
    func a() -> Boo {
        return Boo()
    }
    func b(elm: Boo) {

    }
}
```